# sending values to another page with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I need help on how to send values with jquery when checkbox is checked. so far i have this jquery to disable the checkbox when its checked. But i need to process sql when the checkbox is selected as well. please help me on how to do this.

```
 $('.processCheckbox').change(function() {
         if (this.checked) {
           this.setAttribute("disabled", true);
         } 
       });
```

So i need to send these two values $init and $char to data_process.php when the checkbox is selected.

```
<?php

$init = 0;
$char = 'Y';

echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='processCheckbox'  name='processCheckbox' /></td>";

?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your answer lies in the magic of Ajax. Here's a great tutorial on it: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

When you render the page using PHP you can pass the `$init` and `$char` variables to the client side JavaScript.

Then, in the `$('.processCheckbox').change` handler, you can use the jQuery `$.post` or `$.get` functions to make a request to `data_process.php`, and pass those values as parameters of the request.

For more info:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: so far i have this but it doesnt work 

$('.cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
            if (this.checked) {

@Renish A R
                 $.post('fabProcess.php', {
                 headmark : $($row[HEADMARK]).val(),
                 headmark_id : $($row[ID]).val()
            }, function(response){
                 this.setAttribute("disabled", true),
                         alert(headmark,headmark_id);
            });            
            } 
           });

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('.processCheckbox').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $.post('page.php', {
            val1 : $('#element1').val(),
            val2 : $('#element2').val()
        }, function(response){
            this.setAttribute("disabled", true);
        });            
    } 
});
```

this will post the values of **#element1** and **#element2** to **page.php** page.

Suppose:

```
<input type="text" id="#element1">
<input type="text" id="#element2">
```

in **page.php**

```
$val1 = $_POST['val1'];
$val2 = $_POST['val1'];

//process sql with values
```

in the response area that is **function(response){}**, the codes inside it will execute after success of post method.
so we can specifiy disable method there....

Thank you...